# Unable to install freeipa-server package during offline install on Centos 8 Stream

Tags: centos8, freeipa, dnf

This is about installing the freeipa-server package along with its dependencies for an offline install.  This I am trying on a CentOS 8 Stream.

I created a CentOS 8 Stream iso will required packages cached.  i.e., during ISO installation, no internet is used.  At the end of the installation, I have copied all the rpms from dvd into the /repo folder of the local filesystem.  Have also pointed the repo conf to use the local repo while trying to look for any packages.

After the iso installation, I have the `idm:DL1` module enabled.  Below is the output of the command:

```
[root@localhost ~]# dnf module list idm -v
Loaded plugins: builddep, changelog, config-manager, copr, debug, debuginfo-install, download, generate_completion_cache, groups-manager, kpatch, needs-restarting, playground, repoclosure, repodiff, repograph, repomanage, reposync
DNF version: 4.7.0
cachedir: /var/cache/dnf
User-Agent: constructed: 'libdnf (CentOS Stream 8; generic; Linux.x86_64)'
repo: using cache for: local-repo-BaseOS
local-repo-BaseOS: using metadata from Fr 29 Apr 2022 09:59:07 EDT.
repo: using cache for: local-repo-AppStream
local-repo-AppStream: using metadata from Fr 29 Apr 2022 09:59:12 EDT.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:46:01 ago on So 01 Mai 2022 08:03:45 EDT.
Local AppStream Repo
Name               Stream                  Profiles                                              Summary                                                                    
idm                DL1 [e]                 adtrust, client, common [d], dns, server              The Red Hat Enterprise Linux Identity Management system module             
idm                client [d]              common [d]                                            RHEL IdM long term support client module                                   

Hint: [d]efault, [e]nabled, [x]disabled, [i]nstalled
```

After this, I tried installing the freeipa-server using the command:

```
[root@localhost ~]# dnf install freeipa-server -v
Loaded plugins: builddep, changelog, config-manager, copr, debug, debuginfo-install, download, generate_completion_cache, groups-manager, kpatch, needs-restarting, playground, repoclosure, repodiff, repograph, repomanage, reposync
DNF version: 4.7.0
cachedir: /var/cache/dnf
User-Agent: constructed: 'libdnf (CentOS Stream 8; generic; Linux.x86_64)'
repo: using cache for: local-repo-BaseOS
local-repo-BaseOS: using metadata from Fr 29 Apr 2022 09:59:07 EDT.
repo: using cache for: local-repo-AppStream
local-repo-AppStream: using metadata from Fr 29 Apr 2022 09:59:12 EDT.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:47:05 ago on So 01 Mai 2022 08:03:45 EDT.
All matches were filtered out by modular filtering for argument: freeipa-server
Error: Unable to find a match: freeipa-server
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Can anyone help me with what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

For installing modular content, you need to use modular commands:

```
dnf module install idm:DL1/{server,dns}
```

See official documentation [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/installing_identity_management/preparing-the-system-for-ipa-server-installation_installing-identity-management#installing-packages-required-for-an-idm-server_preparing-the-system-for-ipa-server-installation)

Comment: Thanks for the hint but it did not work.  failed with below error

# dnf module install idm:DL1/{server,dns}
Last metadata expiration check: 2:13:58 ago on Do 05 Mai 2022 01:30:39 EDT.
Unable to resolve argument idm:DL1/dns
Unable to resolve argument idm:DL1/server
No match for package ipa-healthcheck
..
No match for package ipa-healthcheck-core
..
Error: Problems in request:
broken groups or modules: idm:DL1/dns, idm:DL1/server, idm:DL1/dns, idm:DL1/server, idm:DL1/dns, idm:DL1/server, idm:DL1/dns

Comment: It seems like, though the module idm:DL1 is enabled, dnf is not looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

[Packages in locally hosted repository are not seen by dnf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60457682/packages-in-locally-hosted-repository-are-not-seen-by-dnf?rq=1)

Adding `module_hotfixes=true` to the repo definition helped solve the issue.